# Feasibility of Visualising Skeleton and Point Cloud Data in Open3D

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I need to visualise point-cloud and skeleton data simultaneously - in real time and python. Is this feasible with open3d? Does anyone with point cloud experience have any better library recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding your question correctly. You can visualize both the skeleton and the point cloud at the same time using Open3D. Here is a snip of code I did this in.

```
clustered, labels = cluster(pc_name)
skel = skeletonize(clustered)
skel.paint_uniform_color([1, 0, 0])
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([skel, clustered])
```

Here, I have a point cloud (clustered) and its skeleton (skel). (cluster and skeletonize are functions I wrote myself.) I painted the skeleton red to make it distinguishable. I hope this helps and answered your question. Please let me know if I can be of better help.